# Minimalistic GPS tracking app recording to GPX

Tags: android, gps

I need some really minimalistic app for GPS tracking for my old Android device. The free space on the SD card is really low, so any apps such as RunKeeper or Endomondo are tens of times too big.

Is there some app, that is doing only the one thing, namely recording the GPS trace and exporting it to some widely recognized format, like GPX? Such app shouldn't have to be more than 100kb. The smaller, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moose is pretty right with [his answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3476/185): your 100 kB limit makes this task almost impossible. So we can only try to get as close as we can, but not fully match your requirements.

Browsing a [list of available candidates](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=132) shows the good ones start at a size above 500 kB, which is exceeding your limit more than 5 times. However, there's one candidate coming quite close: **[Trax2Earth](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.kmm.trax2earth)** reports its size with ~175 kB. And it matches your other requirements:

- recording your "GPS trace": Yes.
- offering to export them into a common format: GPX & KML are supported.
- additional feature: manually add POIs on-the-fly

One thing to keep in mind: its last update was back in 12/2010, so it doesn't look like it's actively maintained anymore.

---

- A candidate matching your size requirement would be **[ActiveGPS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ellipsoidmobile.activegps)** (~75 kB). Tracks, saves to your SDCard – but I'm not sure which format is being used here.
- Just to prove moose wrong: [Location Log](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.armooo.locationlog) sums up to 27 kB. Unfortunately, it cannot export its data (at least it's not mentioned). And it was last updated in 6/2010, so I wouldn't expect that feature to be added "any time soon" ;)

Comment: Interesting apps to look at. Neither tracking nor writing to XML requires using any external libraries on android, so I was sure 100kb is no way of problematic limit.

Comment: An app strictly sticking to your requirements, and not back-packing any ad modules, should easily be able to stay within the 100KB limit, too, indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement that the app should have less than 100kb makes it impossible. [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=h.w) claims to have only 3430 bytes = 3.4 kB in size. But it only shows hello world. You want much more than that.

A good app that does not have too much overhead is [My Tracks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks&hl=de).

Comment: How about 27 kB (see my answer)? Even if that candidate might be lacking the export feature, another 10 kB should do that I'd say ;)